# How to pass Hashmap data to BaseAdapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am currently implementing Sectioned Listview Adapter [PinnedSectioned Listview](https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview)

Currently i have changed the implementation to base adapter but I am facing some problem in passing the values to the base adapter

How can I pass Hashmap value to the adapter.

Example-

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Test>> example = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Test>>();
```

**Base Adapter implementation**

```
static class MyPinnedSectionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements PinnedSectionListView.PinnedSectionListAdapter{

    private ArrayList mList;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<Item> value;
    public static final int FIRST = 0;
    public static final int SECOND = 1;
    int size=0;
    private String[] mKeys;

    private Map<String, ArrayList<Item>> mData = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>>();

    public MyPinnedSectionListAdapter(Context context, Map<String, ArrayList<Item>> map){
        mList=new ArrayList();
        mData=map;
        mKeys = mData.keySet().toArray(new String[mData.size()]);
        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Item>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            value= entry.getValue();
            size+=value.size();
            System.out.println();

        }
        System.out.println("size" + size);
        mList.addAll(map.entrySet());
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType) {
        if(viewType == SECOND){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }




    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return mData.get(mKeys[position]);
    }



    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        if(viewType == FIRST){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
            String key = mKeys[position];
            String Value = getItem(position).toString();
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(Value);

        }
        if(viewType == SECOND){
            String key = mKeys[position];
            String Value = getItem(position).toString();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.section,parent,false);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(Value);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<Item> item = (ArrayList<Item>) getItem(position);

         if (item.get(position).type == 0){
             return FIRST;
         }else{
             return SECOND;
         }

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**POJO:**

```
static class Item {

        public static final int ITEM = 0;
        public static final int SECTION = 1;

        public final int type;
        public final String text;

        public int sectionPosition;
        public int listPosition;

        public Item(int type, String text) {
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return text;
        }

    }
```

**CODE:**

HashMap> example = new HashMap>();

```
        ArrayList<Item> test1 = new ArrayList<Item>();

        test1.add( new Item(Item.SECTION, "Section1"));
        test1.add( new Item(Item.ITEM, "Section2"));
        test1.add( new Item(Item.ITEM, "Section3"));

        ArrayList<Item> test2 = new ArrayList<Item>();
        test2.add( new Item(Item.SECTION, "Section4"));
        test2.add( new Item(Item.ITEM, "Section5"));
        test2.add( new Item(Item.ITEM, "Section6"));

        example.put("1", test1);
        example.put("2", test2);

        setListAdapter(new MyPinnedSectionListAdapter(this,example));
```

I am getting ouput like :

[Section1 , [Section 2], [Section3]

[Section 4],[Section 5],[Section 6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you not making **constructor** for your `MyPinnedSectionListAdapter` with `HashMap<K,V>` argument. and pass your `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Test>> example` to it,

Something like,

```
public MyPinnedSectionListAdapter(Context context, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Test>> hashMap){...}
```

**Edit:**

As per  @av_lee 's comment.

You can use [Guava's Multimap class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)
with properties like,

- A key is contained in the multimap if and only if it maps to at least
  one value. Any operation that causes a key to have zero associated
  values has the effect of removing that key from the multimap.
- The total entry count is available as size().

Comment: I tried but Integer represents sections and Arraylist represents the items how to can return the size ?

Comment: For this you have to make custom adapter. Which has size counted accordingly each sectioned Arraylist's size in its `getCount()`.

Comment: ok.Is there any other way to implement this ? Instead of passing Hashmap ?

Comment: Make a simple `ArrayList` of **Custom Object** which has two fields `1 int section` and `2 your data value`. Now on `getView()` of Adapter just add List Section when Custom Object field section change its values. - But this is not a standard way to do this.

Comment: @srikanth gr There are plenty of ways. One good and easy would be to use Guava's Multimap class: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: Yes, in Guava's Multimap total entry count is available as size() and your one key references to multiple values.

Comment: @user370305 ok will try both the implementation.

Comment: was able to do with custom objects.